# Extract access token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm new to Spring Boot and I'm trying to write a simple app to learn more about OAuth2. My security config current is

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login().successHandler((request, response, authentication)->{

            System.out.println("Authorities are " + authentication.getAuthorities());
            OidcUser user = (OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println("attributes are" + user.getAttributes());
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
        });
    }
```

Is there away to add hooks to the whole oauth2Login() process to extract the access token? OidcUser only contains idToken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way to extract access token you can use principal extractor, principal extractor is an interface that helps us to get all the details from that token itself.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor

Use the link above to understand the flow and implement the same